# Erro com navegação Ajax ("XMLHttpRequest cannot load...")

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Estou tentando utilizar uma navegação sem refresh na pagina, mas quando clico no link, da esse erro:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Caminho.../paginas/login.html. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Usei esse `login.html` só como teste.

arquivo `navegacao.js`, o que faz a magia acontecer:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var content = $('#conteudo');

        //pre carregando o gif
        loading = new Image(); loading.src = 'imgs/loading.gif';
        $("#c_i_up a").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            content.html( '<img src="imgs/loading.gif" />' );

            var href = $( this ).attr('href');
            $.ajax({
                url: href,
                success: function( response ){
                    var data = $('#conteudo').html(response);

                    //apenas atrasando a troca, para testar o loading
                    window.setTimeout( function(){
                        content.fadeOut('slow', function(){
                            content.html( data ).fadeIn();
                        });
                    }, 100 );
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

arquivo `index.html` resumido:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/navegacao.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="conteudo">
        <div id="c_i_up">
            <a href="paginas/login.html">Teste</a>
        </div><!--c_i_up-->                 

    </div><!--conteudo-->
</body>
</html>
```

**Obs: usei o navegador Chrome e Firefox para testar.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O erro está acontecendo porque você está acessando a URL como um simples caminho no seu computador. Se você colocar esses scripts dentro de um *webserver* (Apache, IIS) este erro não ocorrerá.

Os navegadores possuem algo chamado de "política de mesmo domínio", que, resumidamente, significa que o navegador só vai carregar arquivos via XMLHttpRequest se o destino estiver exatamente no mesmo domínio da origem (que consta na barra de endereços do navegador).

Quando você abre arquivos no seu navegador, em que a barra de endereços inicie com algo parecido com:

```
file:///arquivos/pagina.html
```

o mesmo possui uma origem nula. Seria necessário acessar através de um webserver, onde o endereço ficaria algo parecido com:

```
http://localhost/pagina.html
```

Comment: Eu tinha me esquecido disso rs, é que eu tava fazendo só pra testar mesmo. Obg!