# Consumir WebService de um link externo

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, web-service

Ao consumir um *webService* de uma URL externa através do do *link* no *browser* http://api.postmon.com.br/v1/cep/30640-240 retorna a seguinte mensagem JSON:

> {"complemento": "de 9201 ao fim - lado \u00edmpar (lado par pertence
>   a(o) Contagem)", "bairro": "Barreiro", "cidade": "Belo Horizonte",
>   "logradouro": "Avenida Teresa Cristina", "estado_info": {"area_km2":
>   "586.522,122", "codigo_ibge": "31", "nome": "Minas Gerais"}, "cep":
>   "30640240", "cidade_info": {"area_km2": "331,401", "codigo_ibge":
>   "3106200"}, "estado": "MG"}

Como consigo recuperar estes dados?

Tenho usado o Código:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCep" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button OnClientClick="buscarCep();" ID="btnCep" runat="server" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function buscarCep() {
            var cep = $("#<%=txtCep.ClientID%>").val();
            var url = "http://api.postmon.com.br/v1/cep/" + cep;
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: "{}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    var dados = JSON.parse(data.d);

                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Mais tem me gerado o seguinte erro.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://api.postmon.com.br/v1/cep/30640-240. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:50553' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta assim:

```js
  
    function buscarCep() {
    var cep = $("#txtCep").val();
    var url = "http://api.postmon.com.br/v1/cep/" + cep;
    $.getJSON(url,function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="buscarCep()">Buscar Cep</button>
    <input type="text" id="txtCep" />
```

Existem algumas respostas aqui explicando o motivo disso.

> Os navegadores possuem algo chamado de "política de mesmo domínio",
>   que, resumidamente, significa que o navegador só vai carregar arquivos
>   via XMLHttpRequest se o destino estiver exatamente no mesmo domínio da
>   origem (que consta na barra de endereços do navegador).

Link da resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4762/4533

Comment: Seu código funcionou, poderia me explicar qual a diferença do meu código para o seu?

Comment: @Marconi fiz uma alteração na resposta, dá uma olhada.

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, tente acrescentar a biblioteca jQuery no seu código

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

Isso porque o sinal `$.` é um comando do jQuery, por isso estava dando erro no seu código

Aqui deu certo!
Porém não tive permissão para receber os dados, talvez você tenha essa permissão.

Se der o mesmo erro com você! Tente usar o meu código abaixo, não tem erro!

```
$.getJSON("http://republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php",{"cep" : cep, "formato" : "json"}, function(result){
            //Se deu certo
            if (result['resultado']){
                $("#uf").val(result["uf"]);
                $("#cidade").val(result["cidade"]);
                $("#bairro").val(result["bairro"]);
                $("#logradouro").val(result['tipo_logradouro'] +" "+ result['logradouro'])
                $("#numero").focus();
            }
        });
```

Espero ter ajudado! =)

Comment: Amigo, editei minha resposta, de uma olhada

Comment: Thomas já consta na minha master Page o mesmo jquery.

Comment: Você usa o Firebug ou outro similar??? Se sim, já verificou se gera algum erro no Console?

Comment: Editei a pergunta @Thomas Lima

Comment: Mesmo problema que deu aqui... altera a função de chamada, ao invés de usar o $.ajax, usa o $.getJSON