# localhost não tem acesso a página solicitada

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Estou tentando acessar uma `URL` em `AJAX` mas está dando o seguinte erro:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load [http://endereço da api]. No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. Origin 'http://localhost:50562' is therefore not allowed
> access. Create?Length=0:201 Erro: [object Object]

meu `AJAX`:

```
var url = "[http://endereço da api]";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function (data) {
        console.log("aguarde");
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log("Erro: " + data);
    }
});
```

`JSON` DA PAGINA:

```
        {
        "abertura": "TESTE",
        "atividade_principal": [
        {
        "code": "TESTE",
        "text": "TESTE"
        }
        ],
        "atividades_secundarias": [
        {
        "code": "TESTE",
        "text": "TESTE"
        }
        ],
        "bairro": "TESTE",
        "cep": "TESTE",
        "cnpj": "TESTE",
        "complemento": "",
        "data_situacao": "TESTE",
        "data_situacao_especial": "********",
        "efr": "*****",
        "email": "TESTE",
        "fantasia": "********",
        "logradouro": "TESTEP",
        "motivo_situacao": "",
        "municipio": "TESTE",
        "natureza_juridica": "TESTE",
        "nome": "TESTE",
        "numero": "TESTE",
        "situacao": "ATIVA",
        "situacao_especial": "********",
        "status": "OK",
        "telefone": "TESTE",
        "tipo": "TESTE",
        "uf": "TESTE"
    }
```

Comment: acho que aqui pode te ajudar. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47189/consumir-webservice-de-um-link-externo

Comment: deu o mesmo erro @Marconi

Comment: Tentou o $.GetJson e deu a mesma coisa?

Comment: sim, o mesmo erro @Marconi

Comment: Qual o retorno que vc tem quando abre o link na página? Poderia editar a sua pergunta com ele, mesmo que seja dado fictício.

Comment: Provavelmente o destino, por estar hospedado em um site e você estar rodando o script internamente com localhost, não consegue autenticar para pegar estas informações, as duas páginas estariam hospedadas no mesmo domínio?

Comment: Seu WebService foi desenvolvido em qual tecnologia? Você possui acesso ao código do mesmo?

Comment: estou usando .Net MVC @PedroCamaraJunior

Comment: nao tenho acesso ao código do mesmo @PedroCamaraJunior

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como já foi dito, você está tentando fazer um [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), e a `url` de destino está bloqueando sua solicitação. Como dito pelo erro, você está tentando acessar o domínio `[http://endereço da api]` pelo 'http://localhost:50562', que são domínios distintos.
O site específico não possui uma documentação explicando os tipos de acesso, mas pelo erro está bloqueado esse tipo de requisição.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load [http://endereço da api]. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:50562' is therefore not allowed access. Create?Length=0:201 Erro: [object Object]

Para "contornar" esse erro, você pode criar um `Action` retornando o `json` para você, ficaria assim:

```
public JsonResult BuscaCnpj(string cnpj)
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                var url = "[http://endereço da api]/" + cnpj;
                var json = client.DownloadString(url);
                var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var model = serializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(json);

                return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

Dessa forma você irá obter os dados em `json`. Note que nesta  `serializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(json);` eu estou utilizando [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd264741.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), mas o aconselhável é você criar um Model para esses dados, assim terá dados tipados e será mais fácil de você trabalhar com eles.

Feito isso, basta fazer sua requisição `ajax` chamar a sua `Action`, desta forma:

```
 $.ajax({
                url: 'BuscaCnpj', //Url da Action Aqui
                data: { cnpj: 'MEUCNPJ' },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                type: 'GET'
            });
```

Pronto, assim você terá o resultado abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: mais uma vez obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente

Answer (score 0):

[Politica da mesma Origem](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pol%C3%ADtica_de_mesma_origem)

Tente assim no seu web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1000" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: estou desenvolvendo em .Net MVC

Comment: nossa, desculpe. Vou te ajudar perai.

Comment: magina, tranquilo @durtto

Comment: o seu servidor local é iis?

Comment: você tem um arquivo web.config?

Comment: tenho sim @durtto

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32995/discussion-between-furlan-and-durtto).

Answer (score 0):

Também estava querendo consumir essa API, e estava ocorrendo o mesmo problema a solução é especificar o dataType. Veja o exemplo abaixo funcionando

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

   var param = {};
   param.url = '[http://endereço da api]/' + 53113791000122;
   param.method = 'GET';
   param.success =  function(data){
     console.log(data);
   };
   param.dataType = 'jsonp';
   serviceRest(param);     
 
});



function serviceRest(param){

    $.ajax({
        url: param.url,
        dataType: param.dataType,
        type: param.method,
        data: param.data,
        success: param.success
    });

}
```

DEMO:

```js
  $( document ).ready(function() {
      debugger;
    
       var param = {};
       param.url = '[http://endereço da api]/' + 53113791000122;
       param.method = 'GET';
       param.success =  function(data){
         console.log(data);
       };
       param.dataType = 'jsonp';


       serviceRest(param);
      
        
    
  
     
  });



function serviceRest(param){
 
    $.ajax({
    url: param.url,
    dataType: param.dataType,
    type: param.method,
    data: param.data,
    success: param.success
    });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A API mencionada aceita requisições via AJAX direto, o problema é a ordem dos parâmetros de configuração do ajax, o dataType, deve vir antes do type, nesta ordem funciona tranquilo.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '[http://endereço da api]/53113791000122',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Simplesmente troque o endereço da url para caminho relativo ao invés de estático.

Exemplo: `var url = "/v1/cnpj/MEUCNPJ";` (se estiver no mesmo domínio.)

Se estiver em domínio diferente, o site destino pode estar impedindo o seu acesso pelo site externo, que é o erro reportado pela mensagem. Neste caso, a outra resposta de editar-se o host pode funcionar, desde que o destino não o bloqueie.