# Como executar um URL passando parametros C#

Tags: c#, json, winforms, url

Olá,

Eu estou fazendo para fins de estudo, uma forma de buscar e trazer informações de veículos da tabela fipe direto da api(http://fipeapi.appspot.com/). O que não estou conseguindo fazer de início é executar a URL passando parâmetros. Por exemplo:

Preciso requisitar a lista de marcas de veículos de acordo com o tipo, passando o tipo de veiculo(carro, moto ou caminhão). Fiz um combobox com estas opções para ser escolhida pelo o usuário e armazenadas em uma variável do tipo 'Object'.

```
Object tipoSelecionado = cmbTipo.SelectedItem;
```

Agora o que não sei fazer é na url: http://fipeapi.appspot.com/api/1/[tipo]/[acao]/[parametros].json passar no campo [tipo] a variável '`tipoSelecionado`' e armazenar o resultado em Json no array '`Marcas`'.

```
public class Marcas
        {
            public string key { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string fipe_name { get; set; }
        }
```

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que você quer, mas se a resposta não lhe ajudar, explique melhor que que atualizo a mesma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o [WebClient()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) para isso. Ficaria assim um exemplo:

```
 using (var client = new WebClient())
            {   
                //url de destino. Aqui você pode colocar os parâmetros que desejar
                var url = "http://fipeapi.appspot.com/api/1/carros/veiculos/21.json"; 
                //Download do resultado
                var json = client.DownloadString(url);
                var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                //Descerialização em uma lista dinâmica. Pode adequar sua classe, se rpeferir
                var model = serializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(json);

            }
```

Nesse exemplo, a sua variável `model` já possuirá todos os elementos que serão retornados.

[Nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/103942/20615) eu possuo um exemplo de como implementar utilizando Asp.NET MVC.

Caso esteja utilizando WinForms, basta fazer dessa forma:

```
Object selectedItem = comboBox1.get_SelectedItem();
using (var client = new WebClient())
                {   
                    //url de destino. Aqui você pode colocar os parâmetros que desejar
                    var url = "http://fipeapi.appspot.com/api/1/" + selectedItem.ToString() + "/veiculos/21.json"; 
                    //Download do resultado
                    var json = client.DownloadString(url);
                    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    //Descerialização em uma lista dinâmica. Pode adequar sua classe, se rpeferir
                    var model = serializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(json);
    
                }
```

Desta forma você irá concatenando os valores na url.

Comment: Entendi, exatamente isto que eu queria entender, só faltou um detalhe, este é o link da forma que deve ser solicitado certo (http://fipeapi.appspot.com/api/1/[tipo]/[acao]/[parametros].jso), veja que neste link esta entre colchetes o item tipo([tipo]). Como eu coloco neste exato local a informação que foi escolhida no combobox que eu criei para escolher o tipo de veículo, ou seja, se é carro, moto ou caminhão?

Comment: @StephenWillians Editei a resposta. Você não explicou como está fazendo e nem a linguagem. Fiz com base em Windows Forms, caso seja outra, edite sua pergunta que melhoro a resposta.

Comment: Desculpe @Randrade, mas estou usando a linguagem C# no Visual Studio 2013. 
Eu posso atribuir o resultado em um array para ser apresentado em um DataGridView ou Combobox?

Ex.: jsList[ ] = serializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(json);

Comment: @StephenWillians Ele já está em uma lista, basta adicionar ao seu `DataGridView`. Caso queira mais explicações, abra uma outra pergunta, que ficarei feliz em ajudar.

Comment: Show @Randrade, muito obrigado. Qualquer coisa vou abrir outra pergunta.

Comment: No caso estou usando C#(Windows Forms) posso trocar 'var' por 'string'? Na variável Model que você declarou, qual formato posso utilizar?

Comment: @StephenWillians O `var` obtém o tipo sozinho para você. Mas se quiser declarar, pode, mas não por String. No caso você precisaria declarar um array de objetos, desta forma: `object[] model = serializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(json);`